# If div in iframe has child with specific class do

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I want to add a class to the parent if the child has a specific class.
The problem: It's in an iFrame and I'm not very good with jQuery. 
It don't really has to be jQuery, any other way would be also great. Just notice: The iFrame is on my domain, but I can't access it, because it's generated by a plugin.

If you have any ideas how to fix it, I would appreciate it

My **HTML** looks somewhat like this in devtools:

```
<iframe src="#" id="iFrameResizer0">
<div class="book-day">
    <button class="disabled">Button Text</button>
</div>
<div class="book-day">
    <button class="active">Button Text</button>
</div>

</iframe>
```

and my **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#iFrameResizer0").contents().find(".book-day button")
    if ($('.book-day button').hasClass('disabled')) {
     $(".book-day button").parent().addClass('disabled');
}

});
```

if everything works correct I want my html looks like this afterwards:

```
<iframe src="#" id="iFrameResizer0">
    <div class="book-day disabled">
        <button class="disabled">Button Text</button>
    </div>
    <div class="book-day">
        <button class="active">Button Text</button>
    </div>
    
</iframe>
```

Devtools:

[image]

Comment: Since the button has a class disabled (and not an attribute)  maybe you can resolve the issue on css level by styling your button using this selector `div.book-day.disable button` ?

Comment: @mplungjan As far as I can see it in my devtools it's right in there: https://imgur.com/dMuRwN7

Comment: That is how devtools choose to show it

Comment: @Eineki would be a good idea and I would really prefer to use css. But I have to add the "disabled" to the whole div. Because later I want to hide the disabled ones completely.

Answer (score 2):

***NOTE***: this code has to be executed AFTER the iFrame has loaded and rendered. If you execute this in the head of the parent page without wrapping it in $(function() { ... }), it will not work

You have more than one book-day, you will need to loop:

```
$("#iFrameResizer0").contents().find(".book-day button").each(function() {
     $(this).parent().toggleClass('disabled',$(this).is('.disabled'));
})
```

or perhaps

```
$("#iFrameResizer0").contents().find(".book-day button.disabled").each(function() {
   $(this).parent().addClass('disabled');
})
```

PS: To remove them you do not need to give them a class:

```
$("#iFrameResizer0").contents().find(".book-day button.disabled").each(function() {
   $(this).parent().remove;
})
```

If you still have issue with the timing, try this script right after the iframe tags - right after the `</iframe>`

```
<script>
$("#iFrameResizer0").on("load",function() {
  $("#iFrameResizer0").contents().find(".book-day button.disabled").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove(); // or .addClass('disabled');
  })
})
</script>
```

UPDATE: Alternatively drop the iFrame completely:

Replace the iframe tags with `<div id="iFrameResizer0"></div>`

and add

```
<script>
$("#iFrameResizer0").load("/wp-json/ssa/v1/embed-inner?integration.../type/Reservierung",function() {
    $("#iFrameResizer0").find(".book-day button.disabled").each(function() {
      $(this).parent().remove(); // or .addClass('disabled');
    });
});
</script>
```

---

Example pretending your iframe.content() works as expected (same origin)

```js
$(function() { // on page load. This might STILL be too early
  $("#iFrameResizer0").contents().find(".book-day button.disabled").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('disabled');
  })
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  background-color: grey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="iFrameResizer0">
  <div class="book-day disabled">
    <button class="disabled">Button Text</button>
  </div>

  <div class="book-day">
    <button class="active">Button Text</button>
  </div>
  <div class="book-day disabled">
    <button class="disabled">Button Text</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also thank you. But on my side it's not working. Do you need any further information?

Comment: Any console errors? With the information you have given it should work

Comment: Do you have more than one iframe or other element with the same ID?

Comment: No, thats the only iFrame on that page and there is no other element with that ID. I can share the page with you if this helps. But it would be great if this can be privately.

Comment: Please see update You need to execute the script AFTER the iFrame has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check for every button if it has `disabled` class or not. You can directly select those button having `disabled` class.

In Javascript, you have to iterate for all the buttons having `disabled` class, and add `disabled` class to it's parent. However, in jQuery, as you can see, you can achieve that, without using any loop.

**For JavaScript :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var all = document.querySelectorAll('#iFrameResizer0 .book-day button.disabled');
  all.forEach((item) => {
    item.parentElement.classList.add('disabled');
  })
});
```

**For jQuery :**

```js
$("#iFrameResizer0 .book-day button.disabled").parent().addClass('disabled');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, but besides saying that it's not working I don't know how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Why convert jQuery to DOM access when the selectors work just as well in jQuery???

Comment: @mplungjan Actually I came across the same problem with a question, and the jQuery code was not functional there. And it worked perfectly with JavaScript. I opened the webpage, and tried a few things on console. The jQuery codes were not functional there as it wasn't linked. That's why...

Comment: See my answer for jQuery

Comment: Yeah I checked that, and the comment section as well. Besides that, can you tell how my jQuery code or JavaScript code is wrong :)

Comment: @PranavRustagi Both not working... I update the devtools screenshot with expanded buttons. Maybe this helps

Comment: @PranavRustagi There you go https://i.imgur.com/1FnGX7J.png

Comment: @PranavRustagi unfortunately not. Is there any way to test if I'm even able to add a class there? I don't see any problem with it, because it's on my domain...
Maybe it's important to know that I add the `<script>` on a page where the iFrame is integrated and not in the iframe page itself?

Comment: @Jona even if jQuery is not linked over there, the JS code must work. You can try things on console. Maybe you can create a dummy page and host it somewhere so that, we can try things.

Comment: @PranavRustagi jQuery is working. I've tested it multiple times with `alert` and also `$(document).ready(function () {

if ($("#iFrameResizer0").contents().find(".book-day button").hasClass('disabled')) {
        alert("Erfolg 2")
});` works

Comment: Can you please run a few code segments and tell me the output? That'd be helpful. Inside `ready` event handler, please generate output for `$("#iFrameResizer0 .book-day button.disabled").length` and let me know if it is same as number of buttons having `disabled` class

Answer (score 0):

Since the iframe is observing same-origin policy, This is possible.

**First you need to select your iframe element using the following JS**

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iFrameResizer0');
```

**Now you need to get the content in your iframe**

```
var iframeContent = iframe.contentDocument;
```

**Then select elements inside your Iframe which you wish to modify**

```
var iframeElement = iframeContent.getElementsByClassName("book-day");
var i = 0, ilen = iframeElement.length - 1;
for (var i = 0; i < ilen; i++) {
var button = iframeElement.getElementsByTagName("button");
if(button.className == 'disabled')
{
 iframeElement[i].className == 'disabled';
}
}
```

**Then hide your element using CSS display:none property**

.disabled {display:none;}

Comment: There is no need to use DOM when OP already uses jQuery. My code I posted in my answer works if it is executed after the iFrame loads

Comment: This for loop is wrong `for (var i = 0, ilen = iframeElement.length - 1; i < ilen; i++) {`

Comment: This selector is wrong

`var iframeElement = document.getElementsByClassName("book-day");`

You mean `var iframeElement = iframeContent.getElementsByClassName("book-day");`

Comment: This code is inefficient and will wipe other classes in the div
`if(button.className == 'disabled')
{
 iframeElement[i].className == 'disabled';
}` instead use  `iframeElement[i].classList.toggle('disabled',button.classList.contains('disabled'))`